# How get TITLE command to work with START /D command using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to execute `TITLE` command along with the following command:

```
@echo off
Start /D "MY-DIRECTORY-PATH" cmd /k "prompt $"
```

So that I get the bar title of the command prompt window changed to my own title while the above command works properly.

I tried almost everything I know, no title changed, except when I put `TITLE` command before everything else then it copies what after it to the bar title no matter what and disables `"prompt $"` execution.

Like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJVH5.png)

Thank you in advance and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Uh ... `start "This is my title" /D "MY-DIRECTORY-PATH" cmd /k "prompt $"` should do what you want.

Comment: The START command help is pretty clear on how it works. `START ["title"] [/D path]`. Not sure how you could have missed it if you read the help.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston that worked as charm (Y) :)

Comment: I tried it @Squashman but upon launch it says it can't find ["title"] something like that, but thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @alazizie, I was just pointing out what is in the help file.  The help file matches Harry's example perfectly.  So if you are getting an error then it is most likely user error.